# Why can't I get smooth 60 FPS animation in a WPF application when running a control in a background thread in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, animation

I'm trying to host a control in a background thread, so that it can show an animation at a constant 60 FPS, even if the UI thread gets blocked.  This worked perfectly in Windows 8.1, but since upgrading to Windows 10 it now fails.

I hook the CompositionTarget.Rendering event from the background thread hosting the control, so that the animation can be synchronized with the monitor refresh.  But it seems that as soon as something in the main UI thread also hooks to the Rendering event, frames get skipped whenever a visual hosted in the main UI thread changes.

I can visually see frames being skipped, and according to the RenderTime exposed in the RenderingEventArgs class this confirms that frames are being skipped, because the time delta since the last frame is around 33ms instead of 16ms whenever a frame skip occurs.

The skipping can be induced by hooking the CompositionTarget.Rendering event in the UI thread and doing nothing in the event handler, or by starting a storyboard animation, which I guess is because storyboard animations hook the CompositionTarget.Rendering event to achieve smooth animation.

Here is a simple example project which demonstrates the issue :

[SmoothAnimationTest.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzc-9c-yqGEeVHBZQWN5cFVBTGM/view?usp=sharing)

I've tested it in both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 on several machines, in every case Windows 8.1 runs perfectly with the 'Own Thread' control running at 60 FPS no matter what.  In Windows 10, 'Show Judder 1' reduces the framerate to a constant 30 FPS, and 'Show Judder 2' causes framerate to switch erratically between 30 and 60 FPS, averaging about 45-50.

In both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, pressing the 'Block UI Thread' button results in smooth 60 FPS in the separate thread control.

A solution would be to have the animation run in the UI thread and to remove all blocking code from that thread, unfortunately this is not a simple task as the application I'm working on is complex and there are many places where the UI can block for more than a few milliseconds, which can cause a judder in the animation.

Comment: I can't download the sample project as I'm on a proxied network. What do you mean by "host a control in a background thread"?

Comment: It seems that your application is backwards. You need the UI on the main thread and any long running processes that can block the UI are run on background threads.

Comment: I use HostVisual to contain a custom control in a background thread [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual.aspx)

Comment: It would be preferable to have all long running tasks on a background thread instead, but it would require a lot of work to make the changes to the existing application.  I am wondering what has changed in Windows 10 that has made smooth animations in a background thread difficult, and if there is a workaround without making huge changes to the existing  application.

Comment: It seems results you get are heavily dependent on the value set for the `DispatcherTimer` in `MainThreadControl`. I changed it from current 35 milliseconds to 10 milliseconds and the "smoothness" completely reverted.

Comment: I'm trying to get 60 FPS animation in the background (Own Thread) control so that any code running on the UI thread doesn't stop the animation.  Reducing the timer interval for the main thread control doesn't fix the framerate issue for the background thread control.

Comment: I did not say it fixes anything. I'm saying that this has nothing to do with background threading or Windows 10, as implied in your headline. This is about some arbitrarily set value affecting results you get.

Comment: Ok, I thought that's what you meant by the smoothness being reverted.  From extensive tests it seems that any update in the visual tree caused by a control hosted in the main UI thread causes a frame glitch in the control hosted in the background thread, but only if the main UI thread and the background thread is hooked into CompositionTarget.Rendering, and only in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a full answer, but I thought it best not to write it as a comment.

First, have you verified the issue is not with .Net 4.6? Win 10 ships with .Net 4.6 which replaces .Net 4.5 that shipped with Win 8.1. .Net 4.6 contains quite a few internal changes and new bugs. I would install .Net 4.6 on Win 8.1 to verify this as my first step...
(if the bug is with .Net 4.6 then you have to report it via [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/), but don't get your hopes up. It might take years for the bug to get fixed, if at all)

Secondly, I don't exactly know how you show your control, but it sounds like you need a [second dispatcher](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/). This will require another window though. This way, whatever happens on the Main window, will not affect the secondary window.

Like I said, I don't know if this option is feasible in your scenario. Maybe make the second window borderless, topmost and overlap with the first window...